# Sort two columns in ascending order for each dataframe in a list using a for loop in r

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply

The title says it all. Long story short, I am exhausted and seem to be going round in circles trying to figure out how to get this to work. I have a list of 6 dataframes and I have pasted an example below of the first 2.

**List data**

```
list(`1` = structure(list(Study = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"
), class = "factor"), Scale_1 = c(26.97560976, 24.30081301, 15.82113821, 
15.70731707, 13.2601626, 12.86178862, 11.7804878, 10.69918699, 
10.58536585, 8.593495935, 8.024390244, 5.406504065, 5.406504065, 
5.577235772, 2.674796748, 1.422764228, 1.308943089, 0.227642276
), Scale_2 = c(26.96774194, 24.35483871, 15.74193548, 15.70967742, 
13.22580645, 12.87096774, 11.77419355, 10.67741935, 10.58064516, 
8.548387097, 8, 5.548387097, 5.35483871, 5.322580645, 2.612903226, 
1.483870968, 1.225806452, 0.258064516)), row.names = c(NA, 18L
), class = "data.frame"), `2` = structure(list(Study = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    Group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20"), class = "factor"), Scale_1 = c(20.20325203, 
    16.56097561, 15.76422764, 14.62601626, 7.056910569, 6.601626016, 
    5.691056911, 4.666666667, 4.666666667, 3.642276423, 3.414634146, 
    2.788617886, 2.447154472, 1.650406504, 1.422764228, 0.569105691
    ), Scale_2 = c(20.19354839, 16.5483871, 15.74193548, 14.61290323, 
    7.064516129, 6.580645161, 5.64516129, 4.580645161, 4.612903226, 
    3.612903226, 3.35483871, 2.741935484, 2.419354839, 1.64516129, 
    1.35483871, 0.516129032)), row.names = 19:34, class = "data.frame"))
```

**What I want to do**

What I want to do is create a new list of the same length, but this time have the values for "Scale_1" and "Scale_2" sorted in ascending order in each dataframe. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
#Step 1: Create new (empty) list to store results for for loop
 
result_list<- list()

#Create for loop 

for (i in 1:length(Split_Data)){
result_list[i]<- Split_Data[i][order(Split_Data["Scale_1"])]
}
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried quite a lot of different variants of pretty much the same thing and had little to no success. Each attempt results in either some cryptic error, or the wrong output. Here are a few examples of what I have tried.

1. `result_list[i]<- Split_Data[i][order(Split_Data[c("Scale_1", "Scale_2"])]`
2. `result_list[i]<- Split_Data[i][order(Split_Data[[, c(13,14)]])]`

I also tried other iterations, with double and single brackets but have had limited success because I am pretty new to indexing within for loops...particularly when it comes to working with lists. I am still fairly new to R in general as I don't actually get much time to dedicate towards learning, so any resources would also be appreciated.

I know for loops are generally frowned upon in the R community, and I get `lapply` could probably be used for this, but I have tried that and also had limited success. It all boils down to me being (a) very tired and (b) inexperienced with lists.

I'm sure this will be an easy spy for most people on here, but honestly my inexperience and heavy eyes just aint doing me any favours right now. Thanks in advance to any and all who come up with a solution. Forever grateful for the heros of R.

Comment: @akrun Good spy! Thanks for pointing that out. It should now be rectified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either use `lapply` in `base R`

```
Split_Data <- lapply(Split_Data, function(x) x[order(-x$Scale_1, -x$Scale_2),])
```

or with `map` from `purrr` and `arrange` (by default it is in ascending order)

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
Split_Data <- map(Split_Data, ~ .x %>%
       arrange(desc(Scale_1), desc(Scale_2)))
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun, What I was hoping for was to extend this code so that both ```Scale_1``` and ```Scale_2``` was sorted in descending order and not just ```Scale_1```. Is it possible to sort both in the same line by extending this slightly?

Comment: @Cheddar_Thought do you need as in the update for tidyverse approach

Comment: The base R approach if possible as I am unfamiliar with Purrr. I tried to modify through concatenating but this didn't work. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Cheddar_Thought I already updated the base R approach

Comment: Apologies I never got a notification for the update, only for the comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sometimes, the page won't update unless we refresh it